# Define name with the given name present by the initials

Tags: sas

I try to create a SAS data set with two different variables. Y should be the whole name. The variable Names should by the name with the given name presented by the initials e.g. Johnson Mike should be "Johnson M." and Smith Robert John should be "Smith R. J.". I'm not sure how to create the Names variable, anyone who can help?

```
data names;
Length y $ 40;
Input y &;
Names = y;
DATALINES;
Johnson Mike
Smith Robert John
Jones Linda Mary
Brown Marcus
run;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  You should show some prior effort by explaining what you tried, what resources you read, and describe shortcomings or errors in your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work with a do loop

```
 data names_final;
    set names;
     do _n_ = 1 to countw(Y,' ');
        if _n_ = 1 then name =scan(Y,1);
        else name = catx(' ', name, cats(first(scan(y,_n_)),'.'));
    end;
 run;
```

you can also do

```
data names_final;
set names;
 name = cats(catx(' ', scan(y,1), catx('. ', first(scan(y,2)),first(scan(y,3) ))),'.');
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Function 'countw' 'scan' 'first' and  'catx' may be helpful.
1. Get the number of words of Name;
2. Keep the first word;
3. Do a loop, connect the first word and the first letter of the every single word(expect the first word);